# Is this correct usage of static when auto deletion is expected in C++?

Tags: c++

The [code snippet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) is from Wikipedia.

```
void WriteToFile(const std::string& message) {
  // |mutex| is to protect access to |file| (which is shared across threads).
  static std::mutex mutex;

  // Lock |mutex| before accessing |file|.
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

  // Try to open file.
  std::ofstream file("example.txt");
  if (!file.is_open()) {
    throw std::runtime_error("unable to open file");
  }

  // Write |message| to |file|.
  file << message << std::endl;

  // |file| will be closed first when leaving scope (regardless of exception)
  // mutex will be unlocked second (from lock destructor) when leaving scope
  // (regardless of exception).
}
```

This snippet is to demonstrate RAII. When leaving the WriteToFile scope, mutex will be unlocked. My question is, as mutex is declared as **static**, it should exist until the whole program exit, right? So why would the mutex destructor be called when leaving the scope? I think the mutex destructor only be called once after the main program exit, as the C++ standard specified.

Is there anyone explain this to me?

Comment: The `lock` will be unlocked, not the static `mutex`. `mutex` is static so every thread sees the same mutex. Without `static` you would need another solution to provide the mutex to all threads.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> it should exist until the whole program exit, right?

yes

---

> So why would the mutex destructor be called when leaving the scope?

mutex destructor will not be called. lock guard destructor will be called and it will unlock the mutex.

from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard)

> When a lock_guard object is created, it attempts to take ownership of
> the mutex it is given. When control leaves the scope in which the
> lock_guard object was created, the lock_guard is destructed and the
> mutex is released.

---

> I think the mutex destructor only be called once after the main
> program exit

yes

Comment: OK, I understand. Lock is another object. The point is when leaving, lock destructor is called automatically. That's RAII. So RAII not refer to the mutex object here. I thought mistakely that unlock is an action defined in mutex destructor. Thanks!